# Have any alien species introduced outside the films been later used in the films?

Tags: star-wars

Are there any alien species that were first mentioned in a book, comic, or other non-film source that were then used in a Star Wars film?  By film here I mean the major "Episodes" not Clone Wars. My impression is that the Star Wars films have mostly ignore EU material..

Comment: if you downvote, have the courtesy to explain : )

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, the films have [borrowed extensively from the EU/Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Legends_elements_in_the_films) over the years.

Regarding alien species:

- The Toong were introduced in the 1983 *Lando Calrissian Adventures* book series, and named in *Star Wars Droids*. Ben Quadrinaros, one of the podracers in *The Phantom Menace*, was identified in [the Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/toong) as a Toong.
- The Theelin were introduced in *Dark Empire*, a 1991 comic book. They were added to [post-1997 releases of *Return of the Jedi*](http://www.starwars.com/databank/rystall-sant), and in *Phantom Menace*, as slaves of Jabba
- The Falleen were first introduced in the *Shadows of the Empire* series. A miniature of the Falleen Prince Xixor was used in the Mos Espa crowd scene in *Phantom Menace*, though whether this was intended as anything more than an easter egg is unknown; Falleen characters later appeared in *The Clone Wars* as members of the Black Sun